# Paypal API DoDirectPayment yields Error 10001:Timeout Processing Request

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I am making slow progress with Paypal's API. Currently, making an API call is yielding a timeout error (ERRORCODE:10001):

```
**HttpResponseTIMESTAMP=2013-03-08T01:25:56Z&CORRELATIONID=e00b64a9e4c97&ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=10001&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal Error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout processing request**
```

The above error does not quite indicate much besides that it has timed out. Which means it either timed out attempting to perform the transaction or timed out since it was unable to authenticate the account ? Here is the Name-value-pair string,

```
**METHOD=DoDirectPayment
&VERSION=99.0
&PWD=1362597445
&USER=paypro_1362597411_biz_api1.hotmail.com
&SIGNATURE=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AA.mtioVVAeUWZAnm4W4LmSKUmC8
&IPADDRESS=192.168.237.124
&PAYMENTACTION=SALE
&AMT=660
&CREDITCARDTYPE=VISA
&ACCT=4926081645578645
&EXPDATE=3/2018
&CVV2=333
&FIRSTNAME=Parijat
&LASTNAME=Kalia
&STREET=3302+Folsom+Street
&CITY=3302+Folsom+Street
&STATE=CA
&ZIP=94110
&COUNTRYCODE=US
&CURRENCYCODE=$**
```

The other cue that might be helpful is that when I attempt to login to the **Sandbox Test Site**

with the credentials mentioned, it does not log me in. However, inside my **paypal developer site**, under **test accounts** the very same credentials are clearly stated and I am 100% simply copy pasting the username, password and API. A friend stated that those test accounts for API calls do not let you log in to the Sandbox Test site which comes across as very dubious.

Leads? Solutions ? Critiques ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are receiving is being caused by the date that you are passing over.  It is not in the correct format.  It needs to be ""032018" not "3/2018".  This will then resolve the 10001 error, but hen you will receive a second error saying the version is not supported.  You would need to use verion 98.0 intead of 99.0.  The current verion is 98.0.

Comment: ok that definitely solves the problem i am stating above...however looks like you guys revamped the website yesterday, most of my test accounts in the sandbox dont log me in no more

Comment: There are some issues currently that we are working to resolve.  Try using Firefox or Chrome, as most of the issues seem to be with IE.  Before opening up Firefox or Chrome, clear all of your cookies and cache, and then open up the browser.  Then navigate to developer.paypal.com and log in.  You will have to use an email address that is associated with your live PayPal account.  Once logged in, you can import all of your old test sandbox accounts into the new test sandbox.

Answer (score 5):

DO NOT USE THESE CARD NUMBERS FOR TESTING `DoDirectPayment`: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Instead, make sure you're using the exact testing Credit Card number tied to one of your test users in developer.paypal.com.

To find these:

1. Go to developer.paypal.com and login
2. Go to Dashboard > Sandbox > Accounts
3. Choose the account you want to test against, view 'Profile'
4. Open the Funding tab and use the card number listed there for testing

Comment: Perfectly right, using the exact cc number displayad for the buyer account solved the timout issue for me.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with PayFlow, and learned from their support team  the test numbers listed in the documentation fail because of Fraud detection. Here is a site they recommended to generate test numbers http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com

Answer (score 1):

There might be some issue that we can not identify what we are doing wrong. so here I am listing some of them.

1.
Upgrade to "Business Pro Account"

click on accounts >> select any business account / create business account >> click on profile link >> then you will have popup opened.

If you do'n have upgraded your Business account to "Business pro" then do it first otherwise you won't be able to do payments through credit card.

2.
For me it was issue of credit card number that I was entering.
Do not use any dummy credit card number like '4242424242424242' or '4111111111111111'

Always use credit card number provided by paypal and card expiry date should also from paypal.

You can get your credit card number and card_expiration_date "Under funding menu"

3.
Payment review option should be always on.

Hope this could help to some one :)